# Rails 2.2.2 Form Input Field as Read Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I inherited an older Rails 2.2.2 project and I am trying to make a few text fields read-only but when I added:

```
:readonly => true
```

It isn't working, even after a restart and looking at the source, it looks like Rails is just ignoring that hash value. Here is the entire snippet from the view:

```
<%= f.text_field :password %> <%= link_to "Generate", {},:readonly => true, :class => "small_link_button", :onclick => "generatePassword(); return false;" %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you put readonly on the link, not the text_field.
Consider trying this:

```
<%= f.text_field :password, :readonly=>true %> 
<%= link_to "Generate", {}, :class => "small_link_button", :onclick => "generatePassword(); return false;" %>
```

Comment: To be XHTML compliant you should use `:readonly => 'readonly'` too